# SQL Query to display minimum prices per country

Tags: java, sql, mysql, time-limit-exceeded, swing

I have developed a Tender management System sort of code for one of my client. This is the piece of code :

```
try {
            Connection con = Mycon.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("TRUNCATE tempcalcplan");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.clearBatch();
                ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tempcalcplan SELECT v.conid,c.conname, v.rate, v.venid FROM venprices v LEFT JOIN  country c ON c.conid = v.conid WHERE (v.conid, v.rate) IN ( SELECT v.conid, MIN(v.rate) FROM venprices v GROUP BY v.conid) GROUP BY v.conid");
                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.clearBatch();
                ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from tempcalcplan");

         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This piece of code is designed to function as :

1. Empty the table `tempcalcplan`(Assuming that previous results are stored.)
2. Generating desired data with the help of 2 different tables(Tables are shown below) and storing it in the `tempcalcplan` table
3. Displaying the results of `tempcalcplan` table on a jTable.

Here Are the `country` and `tempcalcplan` table.

1. `country` (Contains 30,000 records)

   ```
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | conid   | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | conname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   ```
2. `tempcalcplan` (Contains 1,80,000+ Records)

   ```
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | conid   | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | conname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | rate    | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | venid   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   ```
3. `venprices`

   ```
   +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | conid | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | rate  | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | venid | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
   +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`
   ```

The results take up to 12-15 minutes to show in the jTable.
I want reduce it to 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Try executing your MySQL query directly in the console.  How long does that take?

Comment: @MTCoster, the MySQL Command Line takes almost same time

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     try {
>             Connection con = Mycon.getConnection();
> ```

This probably could be

```
    try (Connection con = Mycon.getConnection()) {
```

Assuming that this is the `Java.sql.Connection` interface.

Then the `try`-with-resources would be able to `close` the connection for you--exception or no exception.

But that won't help with your speed issues.

You need to determine where the problem lies.  Is it the query at the end?  Is it the population of the table?  The creation of the `jTable`?  Where?

Are there any `conid` values in `venprices` that aren't in `country`?  It would seem that there would have to be, as there are only 30,000 records in `country` and 180,000 in `tempcalcplan`.  Both have `conid` as their primary key, so no duplicates.

Is there an index on `conid` and `rate` in `venprices`?

Comment: The code shown is written in the default constructor of the class. There is a jTable already with object `jTable1`. that is populated on a `JInternalFrame` after selecting an option from menubar.

Yes theere are some` conid` values that are in `venprices` and not in `country`. the `country` table have `conid` as primary key and `venprices` have `conid` and `venid` combined as primary key. so there would be no duplicates for set `(conid,venid)` but there may be duplicates of `conid` as well as `venid` in `venprices`.

There is no index on `conid`.

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL is known for a weak optimizer you should try to rewrite your query to aggregate before join:

```
SELECT v.conid, c.conname, v.rate, v.venid
FROM
 (
   SELECT v.conid, v.rate, v.venid 
   FROM venprices v 
   JOIN
    ( 
      SELECT conid, Min(rate) AS minRate
      FROM venprices
      GROUP BY conid
    ) AS minPrices
     ON v.conid = minPrices.conid
    AND v.rate  = minPrices.minRate
   GROUP BY v.conid
 ) AS v
LEFT JOIN country AS c 
  ON c.conid = v.conid
```

You can run the Derived Tables individually to see which performs slow.